# How do you make a declarative_base-derived class conform to an interface?

Tags: python, interface, sqlalchemy, multiple-inheritance

I've got a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `windows_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filepath` varchar(260) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I've got a base class:

```
class File:
    path: str
    modified: datetime.datetime

    def delete(self):
        os.remove(self.path)
```

I've got a `declarative_base`-derived class:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class WindowsFile(File, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'windows_files'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    filepath = Column(String(260))
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
```

The trouble is, `WindowsFile` is not a very good `File`:

```
>>> file = session.query(WindowsFile).first()
>>> ...
>>> file.delete()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34916>", line 1, in <module>
...
    os.remove(self.path)
AttributeError: 'WindowsFile' object has no attribute 'path'
```

How can I make `WindowsFile` fit the interface, hiding its implementation details? I can't change the database because other stuff is using it, and I can't change the definition of `File` because `windows_files`'s column names are very implementation-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name columns separately from their attribute name by passing the name of the column as the 1st argument to `Column` constructor, so `WindowsFile` could both implement the interface and reflect the table:

```
class WindowsFile(File, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'windows_files'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = Column('filepath', String(260))
    modified = Column('timestamp', DateTime)
```